# clear jboss cache using java code

Tags: java, jboss, ehcache

i want to clear the jboss cache using a java code and for this goal i'im implement the following code:

```
public void clearCache(String s){
        String[] st=CacheManager.getInstance().getCacheNames();
        Cache cache =CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(s);

        cache.flush();
    }
```

is this code correct? and how can i be sure that the JBoss cache is cleared successfully? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three bugs in your code. First, you don't need to query `getCacheNames()`; you're already passing in the name of the cache you're wanting to clear, and you're just throwing away the results in `st`. Next, there's no such method as `CacheManager#getCache(String)`; it's `getCache(String, boolean) throws Exception`, and you need to be passing `s, false` and handling the (far too broad `Exception`). Finally, you never check whether the cache actually exists; if someone passes in a name representing a nonexistent cache, `cache` will be `null`, and you'll get an NPE when you try to `flush()` it.

Comment: thank you so much,but is there a way to be sure that the cache is cleared or no?

Comment: if the cache is exist,is there a way?

Comment: Yes, your call to `cache.flush()` was the piece that was completely correct.